# Commit a changes to a GitHub repository, dowloaded as a ZIP file

Tags: git, github, zip

I have dowloaded a master brach of a project as a ZIP file. I made changes to it, and would like to commit it on a new branch which should be created from master branch.

Should I init a git for a downloaded branch?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you download a git repository from GitHub as a zip file, the "*.git*" folder is not included. The "*.git*" folder tells git that you are inside a repository and holds various info needed by git.
Since when you download a repository as a zip there is no "*.git*" folder, you don't get an actual git repo. This means you have to init it via

```
git init
```

After you have initialized the reo you have just downloaded you have to add the repo's remote:

```
git remote add origin <repo>
```

where *origin* is the remote's name.
Then you have to create the new branch:

```
git checkout -b <branch name>
```

then you just add, commit and push your changes:

```
git add .
git commit -m "commit message"
git push origin <branch name>
```

Anyway I would suggest you clone git repositories via the

```
git clone <repo>
```

command instead of downloading the zip file

Comment: can I edit code and push it to the origin repo as a new branch?

Comment: `git push origin <branch name>` And where would this `origin` come from?

Comment: you miss to add the remote repo link `git remote add origin <URL>`...

Comment: git remotes are usually called *origin*. If you cloned the repository via `git clone` it is added automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you have also cloned the repo, and that you have both the clone and the files from the zip-download on the same machine.

Then I would create a new branch in the clone from the master branch, checkout that branch, and then overwrite the files in the clone with the files where you have made edits. Then you just commit the edits like usual to the new branch.

Answer (score 0):

You should clone the repo.
While downloading the master branch the **.git** is not included.
Or you can init another repo from your system if you have downloaded it from someone else's repo.